# How to make to returns only the titles of translate nodes instead of original nodes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a multi-language site in drupal.
I made a view which returns the titles of some nodes. These nodes are translated in different languages.
How to make to returns only the titles of translate nodes instead of original nodes?

Answer (score 0):

In views set a filter *Node translation: language = Current user's language*

This will do the trick!

Comment: Some nodes for example are not translated, other nodes are translated. For untranslated nodes I want to keep the original title and for the translated nodes I want to see the titles of translate nodes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
I used hook_views_pre_render where I replaced the original nodes with their correspondents(if exist) in current language